# Get the path of selected QTreeView items

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I am newbie with Qt. I am trying to fill a `QTreeView` with all the files and folders of the drive. However, I am not able to get the file and folder paths for on-click event on those files and folders. I am using the code as follows:

```
void client::on_TreeView_clicked()
{
    QModelIndexList list = ui->dir_tree->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    QDirModel* model = (QDirModel*)ui->dir_tree->model();
    int row = -1;
    QStringList filelist;
    foreach (QModelIndex index, list)
    {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = model->fileInfo(index);
        filelist << fileInfo.filePath();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error at this statement:

```
filelist << fileInfo.filePath();
```

The error message is this:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating
>   system. Signal name: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Signal meaning : Could not access
>   the memory. I think it has memory issue somewhere.

My mainwindow.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


 QStringList templist;
 QString filename;
 QString path;
 QString username;
 QStandardItemModel *standardModel;
 QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
standardModel= new QStandardItemModel;
QStandardItem *rootnode= standardModel->invisibleRootItem();
QStandardItem *DriveItem = new QStandardItem("Devices");
rootnode->appendRow(DriveItem);
QIcon disk(":/Images/disk.png");
for(int i=0;i<driveslist.count();i++)
{
    QStandardItem *treeItem1 = new QStandardItem(driveslist[i]);
    treeItem1->setIcon(disk);
    DriveItem->appendRow(treeItem1);
}
QStandardItem *PlacesItem = new QStandardItem("Places");
rootnode->appendRow(PlacesItem);
QStandardItem *placeItem1 = new QStandardItem("Desktop");
QStandardItem *placeItem2 = new QStandardItem("Root");
QStandardItem *placeItem3 = new QStandardItem("Applications");
QStandardItem *placeItem4 = new QStandardItem("Documents");
PlacesItem->appendRow(placeItem1);
QIcon disk1(":/Images/t 1.png");
placeItem1->setIcon(disk1);
PlacesItem->appendRow(placeItem2);
QIcon disk2(":/Images/t 2.png");
placeItem2->setIcon(disk2);
PlacesItem->appendRow(placeItem3);
QIcon disk3(":/Images/t 3.png");
placeItem3->setIcon(disk3);
PlacesItem->appendRow(placeItem4);
QIcon disk4(":/Images/t 4.png");
placeItem4->setIcon(disk4);
ui->treeView->setModel(standardModel);
ui->treeView->expandAll();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_treeView_clicked(QModelIndex index)
{
  On click of this tree items,  treeView_2 will be generated and on click of those items      on_treeView_2_clicked(QModelIndex index) will be called.
}

void MainWindow::on_treeView_2_clicked(QModelIndex index)
{
    QModelIndexList CurrentIndex = ui->treeView_2->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
    QFileSystemModel *model=(QFileSystemModel*)ui->treeView_2->model();
    QList <QString >SelectedPathList;
    if(CurrentIndex.size())
    {
        for(long long ll = 0;ll < CurrentIndex.size(); ll++)
    {
        QModelIndex Index = CurrentIndex[ll];
        QString m_strSourcePath = model->filePath(Index);
        SelectedPathList << m_strSourcePath;
    }
}

}
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simple call `model->filePath(index);`?

Comment: Ya i have already tried it. but it also shows the same error.

Comment: What is the error message? Please paste it here.

Comment: The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.                                                           Signal name: EXC_BAD_ACCESS                                                                   Signal meaning : Could not access the memory.                                                                                                            I think it has memory issue somewhere.

Comment: Can you paste a simple code that reproduces the issue and we can build to test? That is, containing a main.cpp, etc based upon the ssccce.org description.

Comment: Hi Laszlo, i have edited my query.Now can u help me out ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
QFileSystemModel* fileSystem = new QFileSystemModel();
QString myPath = fileSystem->filePath(index);
```